# Equation for induced electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Is the induced electromagnetic field (EMF) always equal to negative rate of change of flux, where $f$ is the flux?
I'm curious how it can be true in every case.

Comment: What are the cases for which you are curious?

Answer (score 0):

It is a manifestation of the fact that the induced current produced as a result of the induced emf will be in such a direction as to produce a magnetic field and hence magnetic flux which opposes the changing flux - Lenz’s law.

If this were not the case the law of conservation of energy would be violated.  In other words no work would have to be done to produce an induced current which in turn could produce a heating effect, or light, or sound, or motion etc.
So when you push a magnet into a coil you will have to do work to produce an induced current. If the negative sign were not there then the magnet would be “sucked” into the coil with no intervention from you and electrical energy would be produced “spontaneously”.

Comment: Actually i was asking whether the equation is valid in all cases..not about the negative sign

Comment: In some cases the emf is purely motional yet we use this equation..i was asking how it is true even in such cases